# How to know who is the caller function in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have defined a function like this

```
    $scope.func1 = function(){

    //some task done here;

     $scope.func2 = functin(){
         //some other task done here
     }
}
```

Now in controller I have called func1; But direct calling for func2 is written on template like

```
<div class="someclass">{{func2 ()}}</div>
<div class="someRandomLinks" ng-click="sometask()">clickMe</div>
```

Now the thing is once func2() is called when this line in complied/executed by browser, but other than that it is also get called on sometask(). But I didn't find any binding or link in between these 2 things.

I know I have give a very very vague and blurry image of what I am facing. If you need more code or exact code, please comment. The reason I didn't put exact comment here is it's very big and messy and I was not sure of in which part of it the problem lies.

CAUTION:**I think my problem is not getting understood. What i want to know is "is it possible to know who is calling func2(), whenever it gets called??**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps..

```
$scope.func1 = function() {
  ...
  // some task done here;
}

$scope.func2 = function() {
  ...

  some other task done here
}
```

In your example, `func2` was defined inside `func1`.

EDIT:

`func2` is called directly because you call it directly in your template. Also, functions are not executed directly if they are just defined inside another function.

Say,

```
function a() {
  ...

  function b() {
    ..
  }
}

a(); // This does not launch b().
```

EDIT 2:

Your `func2` gets called again probably because you call it inside template. That's why, when you click, the template gets refreshed (digested) and runs again.

Comment: Yes that's correct. So whenever func1 is called, func2 runs automatically. But clickMe doesn't call func1 too. func2 is called directly. I hope you are understanding what I am saying.

Comment: I want to know who initiated the call to func2, like in javascript we have argument.callee.caller (something like it)

Comment: You are correct, I call func2 directly, but the problem is it get called again again on execution of clickMe onclick. But strangely I didn't find and called inside clickMe onclick function. am I making myself clear?

Comment: Your calling func2 before it is defined. func2 becomes defined when func1 has been called at least once.

Comment: Thanks for help, I am working on this problem. I will tell you once I get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

not enough reputation to comment so answering..

You are defining func2 inside func1. It wont call it. You have to call explicitly.

```
$scope.func2 = function() {
  ...

  some other task done here
}
$scope.func1 = function() {
  ...
  // some task done here;

  $scope.func2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your question, but I'll try.

The thing is, that you're defining `func2` only when you run `func1`.

The result is that `{{func2()}}` is evaluated to undefined, and therefore you don't see anything.

Take a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ronapelbaum/zvvqkhco/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use this (if i got you right)

```
<div class="someclass">{{func2 ($event)}}</div>
<div class="someRandomLinks" ng-click="sometask($event)">clickMe</div>
```

than in the Ctrl:

```
function func2(event) { ..... }
function sometask(event) { ... }
```

and with the event you can get the element fired the function.

Answer (score 0):

So, in this way you have two test cases.

1. function `func2` is called when browser complete its loading.
2. function `func2` is called by `sometask()`

So,when you called `func2` by `sometask()` passed additional parameter like

```
$scope.func2 = function(str) {     

    if(str==1010)
       console.log("I have called by sometask");
    }else{
       console.log("I have called by browser..");
    }
}

    $scope.sometask  = function() {

      $scope.func2(1010);  
    }
```

Comment: right, from this I will only come to the point that whether func2() is getting called from controller file or from template. But caller will still be unknown to me.

Comment: You can pass the information in the parameter list like I did.Based on that parameter you get caller info

Comment: there is no calling written in sometask() for func2(), that the strange problem.